# Is it possible displaying ldap folder structure with Perl?

Tags: perl, ldap, directory-structure

I will retrieve user informations from a LDAP server. Customer sent me following 3 data:

1. LDAP Server IP
2. Username to authenticate
3. Password to authenticate

This is the 1st time I am working with LDAP so I studied on it. I see that I must use some parameters like cn, dc, ou. Should not customer give this info either? Or customer's info is enough and can I find these parameters by a code displaying folder structure?

Comment: What type of directory it is ? What does the provided username look like ?

Comment: I will retrieve user information. I do not know any other info. My question is whether I must ask this to customer or is there any way to see directory hierarchy of LDAP server

Comment: It would be better for you to know what type of directory you have to work on especially if you are not comfortable with LDAP... you can guess it once you managed to read some entries though. Did you managed to bind and perform a search on it ?

Comment: Don't post an answer to ask another question just update your question, or create a new one if it's not related. I'm going to update my answer to clarify it, you need a valid base dn to perform search.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you want to see is called the directory tree and is made of LDAP "**entries**" (not folders).

You should be able to collect entries from your directory provided that the credentials you've been given are sufficient. For that you need a client library, you can use [Perl LDAP](http://ldap.perl.org/).

Using that library you would do something like :

```
use Net::LDAP;

# Init connection and bind to the directory. 
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new('ldaphost.example.com') or die "$@";
$mesg = $ldap->bind ($binddn, password => $password);

# Perform a search on the whole tree below (and including) the base object.
$mesg = $ldap->search(base => $basedn); 

# Handle error
$mesg->code && die $mesg->error;

# Display results
foreach $entry ($mesg->entries) { $entry->dump; }

$mesg = $ldap->unbind;
```

The code above just print entries to stdout ($entry->dump).

- `$binddn` is the dn to authenticate with. If you've been given a simple username that is not a dn, like 'username' instead of something like `uid=username,dc=example,dc=com`, it would probably mean that you are dealing with Active Directory. In this case you can try to bind with a binddn that corresponds to the following pattern : `'username@example.com'`.
- `basedn` is the dn of the base object entry, the search is performed on the whole tree below (and including) the base object. You will have to specify a valid base dn.

You can try to guess which base dn to use. Domain components (dc) usually match the FQDN but it is not guaranteed it results in a valid base dn (e.g. `'ldaphost.example.com'` would give `'dc=example,dc=com'`). However you can query the server for rootDSE information and retrieve the `namingContexts` (or `defaultNamingContext` if any) and use one of them as the base dn :

```
$ldap->search(base => '', attrs => 'namingContexts');
```

That said, if you really want to display the directory tree, you have better to go with an LDAP explorer like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

Note that LDAP is not limited to storing information in strict "tree" structures, it just have to respects a Directory Information Tree (DIT) nomenclature.